# Download files from server freezes app and loses connection

Tags: android, download, fileoutputstream

I'm triying to download some files from a FTP Server with `FTPClient` (commons-net-3.3).

When click in a button with a AsyncTask I get a list of `FTPFile` s with `listFiles(path);`. Then I download each file of list like this (All of work in the same AsyncTask)

```
FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream("localfile");
InputStream input = mFTPClient.retrieveFileStream("remotepath");
byte data[] = new byte[512];
long total = 0;
int count;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;                             
    Double porcentaje =  ((double) total / (double) tmpFiled.getSize()) * 100;
    publishProgress((int) Math.round(porcentaje));
    desFileStream.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    desFileStream.flush();
    desFileStream.close();
    input.close();
}}
```

In particular in `input.read(data)`. This must be read 1024 bytes but in random iteration read less data than 1024, write it and in the next iteration `input.read(data)` freezes download return timedout exception

After that the internet connection of the dispositive not works

Logcat shows this exception

```
09-19 09:59:06.890: W/System.err(13215): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
09-19 09:59:06.900: W/System.err(13215):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)
09-19 09:59:06.900: W/System.err(13215):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
09-19 09:59:06.900: W/System.err(13215):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
09-19 09:59:06.920: W/System.err(13215):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
09-19 09:59:06.920: W/System.err(13215):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
09-19 09:59:06.920: W/System.err(13215):    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:118)
09-19 09:59:06.920: W/System.err(13215):    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
09-19 09:59:06.920: W/System.err(13215):    at com.asde.telemedicina.FTPHandler.ftpDownload(FTPHandler.java:405)
09-19 09:59:06.920: W/System.err(13215):    at com.asde.telemedicina.FTPHandler.doInBackground(FTPHandler.java:167)
09-19 09:59:06.920: W/System.err(13215):    at com.asde.telemedicina.FTPHandler.doInBackground(FTPHandler.java:1)
09-19 09:59:06.920: W/System.err(13215):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-19 09:59:06.920: W/System.err(13215):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-19 09:59:06.920: W/System.err(13215):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-19 09:59:06.930: W/System.err(13215):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-19 09:59:06.930: W/System.err(13215):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-19 09:59:06.930: W/System.err(13215):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-19 09:59:06.930: W/System.err(13215): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
09-19 09:59:06.930: W/System.err(13215):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
09-19 09:59:06.930: W/System.err(13215):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:141)
09-19 09:59:06.930: W/System.err(13215):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
09-19 09:59:06.930: W/System.err(13215):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
09-19 09:59:06.930: W/System.err(13215):    ... 14 more
```

For example in Motorola Moto G never occurs however in other dispositives frecuently occurs. I',e tried two ftpservers.

Can cause the problems local file permissions?

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: did app crash ? u can make progress bar in case of slow connection and large files

Comment: I edited the first message. The problem seems to be a Timeout but only occurs in some dispositives.

Comment: I added more info, the problem seems to be in ´input.read(data)`.

Comment: If the problem is that your are getting the crash in the second iteration of the loop, probably must not close the input until finish all iterations in the loop. Move input.close() out of the loop and try again.

Comment: I need to download multiple files, I close the input when each file is completed. The problem is when read data from server.

Comment: Did you try to use any third party library like Ion?

Comment: After a lot of hours of dummy debug I think I found the problem. The internet connection through the WIFI of my home goes down. I've tried in other connection and works like a charm :p

Comment: Oh guy, i'm glad for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your error could be caused by multiple active downloads connection which saturate your network connection. And generate a timeout exception. It should explain the random characteristic of you error. To avoid it I think you have to limitate the number of simultaneous download.

After doing a little search on google I've also carried out (even if i think that isn't your case) that the  "Connection Timeout" error In Ice Cream Sandwich and earlier could be related to DNS double caching. See this [Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7904)

Comment: Hi, I not think that the problem be related with the bug of Ice Cream because in a phone with Android 4.4.4(KitKat) also occurs. About the simultaneous download, I dont start new donwload until the last is already finished. When `input.read(data)) != -1` I close the input and the ouput and open a new.

Comment: And the connection is always stable?

Comment: It couldn't be caused by the connection which goes down?

Comment: I tested on 3G connection and runs fine so that I think is a problem of my home connection

Comment: Couldn't you try it over another WiFi connections?

Comment: It is an error that isn't caused by your code but it's the network connection which leaks the only thing you can do is throw the exception

Answer (score 1):

I've done little search and try that;

```
FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream("localfile");
mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // File type can be changed
boolean status = mFTPClient.retrieveFile("remotepath",desFileStream);
```

Comment: I dont know how can fix this code my problem. If you read my code you see that I get the file like a stream.

Comment: You get streams but directly convert it to file and save on phone. This code is getting the file and save it to storage without any InputStream operation.

Answer (score 0):

> In particular in input.read(data). This must be read 1024 bytes but in random iteration read less data than 1024

No it's not "must". Here is what Java doc sais:

> **`int read(byte[] b)`** 
>   Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b.

This function reads data up to buffer size, not exactly that size.

> InputStream input = mFTPClient.retrieveFileStream("remotepath");

What is "remotepath"?
Is it a file, or is it a directory?

In case it's a file, problem is in the line `input.close();`, because after you've read few bytes on the first iteration you close your stream and then trying to read from the closed stream on the second iteration (like already been said in comment).

In case it's a directory, then you just can't download it like you're trying to. There's a LIST command in FTP protocol, which lists files in a current directory. You must list those files and download every of them separately.

Comment: Hi, remotepath is a File and I only close the input when `input.read(data)) != -1` ie when the file is already downloaded